# Rails display two modals from same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails view with two icons.  Each icon should open a different modal (using a partial).

The issue is that both icons are opening the same modal (the first one).

Here is the code to display the modals:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#workorder-<%= workorder.id %>">
  <i class="icon-list"></i><%= workorder.wologs.count %>
  <%= render :partial => "wologs/history", locals: {workorder: workorder} %>
</a>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#workorder-<%= workorder.id %>">
  <i class="icon-ok-sign"></i><%= workorder.tasks.count %></a>
  <%= render :partial => "tasks/taskslist", locals: {workorder: workorder} %>
</a>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post the Javascript code that shows the modal on the event? I'm pretty sure there is a problem on the selector since the two a tags have the same href attribute

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I'm pretty sure this is Boostrap, no need to put Javascript. And I'm also pretty sure your guess is right :)

Comment: It is bootstrap. Should I somehow change the href on one?

Comment: I'm thinking I need to change the href on this display page and each modal - right?

Comment: Changing the name of the href worked - thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrYoshiji already mentioned the reason is two links point to same id, so same modal launched.

I would like to add that it's also incorrect to put the modal body inside link, if the partial is modal body.

According to Bootstrap example:

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

The link and modal are two totally different divs.

So the fix is:

Launch partial in different div and assign different ids to them.